# can't add product to sylius-db from command

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $factory = $this->getContainer()->get('sylius.factory.product');
        $manager = $this->getContainer()->get('sylius.manager.product');

        $product = $factory->createNew();
        $product
            ->setName('Foo')
            ->setDescription('Nice product');

        $manager->persist($product);
        $manager->flush(); // Save changes in database.
```

So I want to add a product from a command. But I'm always getting this Error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setDescription() on null in C:\Users\Coffee-Bike\IntelliJIDEAProjects\sylius-shop\acme\src\AppBundle\Command\Collmex\ImportProductsFromCollmexCommand.php on line 46
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\Users\Coffee-Bike\IntelliJIDEAProjects\sylius-shop\acme\bin\console:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() C:\Users\Coffee-Bike\IntelliJIDEAProjects\sylius-shop\acme\bin\console:28
PHP   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() C:\Users\Coffee-Bike\IntelliJIDEAProjects\sylius-shop\acme\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:130
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() C:\Users\Coffee-Bike\IntelliJIDEAProjects\sylius-shop\acme\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application.php:81
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() C:\Users\Coffee-Bike\IntelliJIDEAProjects\sylius-shop\acme\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:223
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() C:\Users\Coffee-Bike\IntelliJIDEAProjects\sylius-shop\acme\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:887
PHP   7. AppBundle\Command\Collmex\ImportProductsFromCollmexCommand->execute() C:\Users\Coffee-Bike\IntelliJIDEAProjects\sylius-shop\acme\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command.php:264

Fatal error: Call to a member function setDescription() on null in C:\Users\Coffee-Bike\IntelliJIDEAProjects\sylius-shop\acme\src\AppBundle\Command\Collmex\ImportProductsFromCollmexCommand.php on line 46
```

But I'm juts following this documentation [here](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusProductBundle/product.html).
And  this is the same procedure. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well the error suggests setName is returning null instead of the product instance - maybe you need to call setDescription directly on product rather than chaining the method calls?

Comment: Ok, seems like method chaining doesn't work in this case. thanks. still wondering why

Comment: Outdated documentation maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs in The Book section here: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/book/products/products.html

Comment: So method chaining like they described in the docs as well isn't possible?